# Test error callback in Angular with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

How do you test an error callback in an Angular controller like the following:

**controller.js**

```
  Note
    .query()
    .$promise
    .then(
      function( notes ) {
        // success
      },
      function() {
        // error
      }
    );
```

In my spec, I can put some random object in the call to `queryDeferred.resolve()` and test the success callback. But how do I test the error case?

**spec.js**

```
//= require spec_helper

describe( 'NoteListCtrl', function() {
  // edited for brevity...

  beforeEach( inject( function( $controller ) {

    NoteMock = {
      query: function() {
        queryDeferred = $q.defer();
        return { $promise: queryDeferred.promise };
      }
    }

    spyOn( NoteMock, 'query' ).andCallThrough();

  }));

  describe( 'Note.getNotes', function() {

    describe ( 'Note.query', function() {

      beforeEach( function() {
        $scope.getNotes();
        queryDeferred.resolve( ????? ); // What goes here?
        $rootScope.$apply();
      });

    });


  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reject`:

```
queryDeferred.reject(someData);
```